# Is there a way to integrate recorded digital media evidence into a pilot report?

Tags: pirep

If I encounter something during flight that I feel other pilots in the area at that time need to be aware of, the standard procedure is to file a pilot report.  If I have taken a photo or video of the phenomenon or incident, is there any way to integrate this digital media evidence file into the pilot report?  Can you type in website(s) link(s) to the digital media?

Answer (score 5):

No. PIREP's follow a strict format that predates that kind of digital media. They must be compatible with distribution via AFTN and ACARS. PIREP's are created from a limited character set, and there is no way to attach any kind of digital media.

Comment: Not to mention that the time-sensitive nature of PIREPs renders digital documentation typically unnecessary and obsolete.